# Flash player ( debugger ) - show again the errors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have pressed "Dissmiss all" button inside Debugger window of Flash player, and it stoped permanently showing me the errors on the page.

- How to resume showing the errors inside Flash debug window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your personal Windows folder (documents and settings\your name), you may find a mm.cfg file.
Modify the following line:

```
SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=0
```

Comment: it is only on Google Chrome and Safari with Stoped debuging, on Internet Explorer is still showing the debuger window.

Comment: I've always just restarted my browsers and the dialog has come back.  Have you tried that?